# Cellphone Backups to Computer and a Viewer

Tags: windows, android, ios, backup, mobile

I am looking for software to backup Cellphones (texts photos videos contacts and call history) both IOS and Android to an external hard drive or something else but also to have a viewer to review these backups if I am looking for a certain text and to see when someone called the person from the call history.

Mostly I want to catalog phones before I wipe them and reuse them for other purposes and keep the information to review later down the road if an employee were to leave the organization I could review who they texted and called years down the road if I found out of any wrong doing on their part and **clear their name using this information.**

**Its important to be able to review it on a computer as cellphones keep changing who knows how long a certain call history or SMS may work on a certain model of phone.**

All recommendations are appreciated !

Features:

- Both IOS and Android
- Viewer for Windows
- Can be backed up once handed to me as they resign from the organization (I am not worried about regular backups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android phones, you can use [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/en/) that can sync between multiple android phones and its Windows Desktop app. It is free, even though the developer accepts donations. It can backup SMS, files, audio, etc. (It can also sync with user's outlook if required).
You can set "archive calls" length in its settings e.g. 6months, 1 year, unlimited...

Potentially many users are you going to back up?

I don't have much experience with IOS, so I don't have any suggestions for that.

Comment: I would prefer both IOS and Android in the same product but if it comes down to it I will use two to resolve this issue if needed. I will look at it and see if I can use it along with an IOS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Syncios](https://www.syncios.com/features.html) to back up the contents of my Android phone.  A [free and paid version](https://www.syncios.com/version-compare.html) is available and it works for both Android and IOS.  Your requirements would be met by the inexpensive paid version.

Comment: Wow thank you, I skipped over this the first look through because I didn't see on the website that it had a viewer which is a must for Windows. Thank you I will give this a try and see if it has what I need. Cheaper than the other two alternatives I was looking at by a lot.